# Bootstrap carousel issue in ajax call

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap carousel slide is not working in ajax success call. Ajax call is completed without any issue but `$("#myCarousel").carousel();` is not working & the next slide is not shown.

```
<head>
....
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#myId').click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#myId").attr( "action"),
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',           
            contentType : 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#myCarousel").carousel();
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    });   
  </script>



</head>
<body>
.....
<div class="container">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
            ...
                <button id="myId" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/create" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h2>Slide 2</h2>
            ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it work outside of the ajax call?

Comment: yes... If I write it outside ajax call but inside document.ready function then it works fine.

Comment: And the `success` callback is definitely being called? If you put `console.log($('#myCarousel'));` before the carousel call does it log the JQuery object in the developer console?

Comment: it prints this "[div#myCarousel.carousel.slide, context: document, selector: "#myCarousel", jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, toArray: function…] "

Comment: Something to try: change the carousel call to `$('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: 2000 });`

Comment: Tried that... didn't help but the same works outside ajax call

Comment: Looks like you're doing nothing wrong. I would create an [issue on github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues) for bootstrap...

Comment: @user1298426 are you just trying to move to the next slide or initialize the carousel? `$('#myCarousel').carousel('next')` is the proper syntax for moving to the next slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax to move to the next slide is `$('#myCarousel').carousel('next');`